# Not overwriting saved xml files in C# Window Form

Tags: c#, xml, windows, winforms

I am fairly new to C# and I was wondering how to keep an XML file from being overwritten if one already exists on the install. In the application, there are two files that contain info to connect to the Database. One of them is relatively dynamic, but the other is saved at the setup. If I do a publish and try to update the application it always overwrites both files. Any thoughts?

Comment: You said WinForms, but then you say "publish" which I associate with web sites

Comment: It is a Winforms Desktop Application with OneClick Publishing.

Comment: I apologize ClickOnce*

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists with `File.Exists(Path)`

You can look here for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-3.1

If this does not work you can try to read that file and if there is any data there just sont delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are refering to configuration settings.

While designing your settings, in the designer, set scope to "User". This will bind the setting to the users local app settings, and will not be overwritten.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time